# Adding middleware to check API key & pass

Tags: node.js, express, restify

I am just starting out learning node.js after deciding to write my next API using node and restify. There will only be a couple of users accessing the API and it will be a strictly private one - no one else should be able to access it.

Basically, I need away to check that "key" and "pass" params are supplied (and valid) for every request. So, I thought I could add some middleware that is executed before everything else to do the checking.. e.g.:

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'test'
});

server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.key == null) {
        console.log("No API key supplied");
        return next(new restify.NotAuthorizedError("No API key supplied"));
    }
});
server.use(restify.bodyParser());


server.listen(8888, function() {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hello World');
    return next();
});
```

Browsing to `localhost:8888/test` gives `{"code":"NotAuthorized","message":"No API key supplied"}` which is what I want.

However, browsing to `http://localhost:8888/test?key=a` still gives the same message..

Clearly, I'm not going about this the right way. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I needed to add `restify.queryParser()` to parse the GET params. Now, this works:

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'test'
});

server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.key == null) {
        console.log("No API key supplied");
        return next(new restify.NotAuthorizedError("No API key supplied"));
    } else return next();
});

server.listen(8888, function() {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hello World');
    return next();
});
```